# USB modes, for transfering files with AFT

Tags: usb, macos

Why do I have to go into the phone (Galaxy S7 Edge) everytime I connect it to my Mac and manually switch the USB option from charging to MTP??

This is annoying and a hassle, why can't the phone detect that its plugged in and switch modes itself?

I dont want to have the phone in developer mode all the time, i just disabled it because its not applicable to me but now I have to turn it on every time I want to transfer files onto my phone.

There has to be a better way to do this.
Any explanations?

Answer (score 0):

You have to change it every time because of security changes in Android, and there is no easy way around it without root on a stock device.

The reason is so anyone can't just connect to your phone without screen being unlocked, it is purely a security enhancement.